# How to reference DISTINCT column names in a CTE or subquery?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, distinct

I need to generate a list of unique column pairs from a table, but Postgres seems to not like my approach.

My CTE approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT(col1, col2)
  FROM table1
  WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
  AND col2 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT json_build_object('col1', cte.col1, 'col2', cte.col2)
FROM cte;
```

Gives me this error:

> ERROR:  column cte.col1 does not exist
>  LINE 8: SELECT
> json_build_object('col1', cte.col1, 'col2...

I also tried a subquery:

```
SELECT json_build_object('col1', col1, 'col2', col2)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(col1, col2)
  FROM table1
  WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
  AND col2 IS NOT NULL
) AS temp;
```

Which failed in basically the same way:

> ERROR:  column "col1" does not exist 
> LINE 1: SELECT
> json_build_object('col1', col1, 'col2...

It seems I can't reference the column names as normal due to the `DISTINCT`. What should I do instead?

Comment: Might be a weird Postgresql thing but AFAIK distinct is not a function, it applies to rows.  The parenthesis around col1, col2 are a syntax error

Comment: @LoztInSpace, true, DISTINCT belongs to SELECT DISTINCT, and is _set quantifier_, not a function. However, the parentheses makes col1 and col2 in `(col1, col2)` to be returned as a single row type column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the mistake to use parentheses. `DISTINCT` is *not* a function.

The parentheses are interpreted as a [*row constructor*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS), so your CTE returns only a single value of type `record` (and with a name chosen by the database).

Remove the parentheses, and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

Misplaced parentheses aside, since you prepare relevant columns in a subquery anyway, just use the simpler [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT to_json(temp)
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
   FROM   table1
   WHERE  col1 IS NOT NULL
   AND    col2 IS NOT NULL
   ) temp;
```

Comment: I figured there was an easier way, thanks :-)